# how to show hide multiple ids' in ready function with a single loop in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I wanted to make it as a loop for this ready function but I ended up doing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#p1-show').click(function () { $('#p1').show(); });
  $('#p1-hide').click(function () { $('#p1').hide(); });

  $('#p2-show').click(function () { $('#p2').show(); });
  $('#p2-hide').click(function () { $('#p2').hide(); });

  $('#p3-show').click(function () { $('#p3').show(); });
  $('#p3-hide').click(function () { $('#p3').hide(); });

  $('#p4-show').click(function () { $('#p4').show(); });
  $('#p4-hide').click(function () { $('#p4').hide(); });

  //there will be ids' for 300+ show hide

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can associate the element to be `show()` and `hide()` using custom `data-*` prefixed attribute, which can be retried using `.data(key)`.

Using it you can use Class Selector to bind event handler.

*HTML*

```
 <button class="show" data-target="#p1">show p1<button>
 <button class="hide" data-target="#p1">hide p1<button>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show').click(function () {
        $(this).data('target').show();
    });
    $('.hide').click(function () {
        $(this).data('target').hide();
    });
})
```

Comment: I was part way through writing an answer which basically said this

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i =1; i< 5; i++){ 
        $(`#p${i}-show`).click(function () { $(`#p${i}`).show(); });
        $(`#p${i}-hide`).click(function () { $(`#p${i}`).hide(); });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop. Use substring matching attribute selectors.

```
$("[id$=show]").on("click", function () {
    $("#" + this.id.replace("-show", "")).show();
}):

$("[id$=hide]").on("click", function () {
    $("#" + this.id.replace("-hide", "")).hide();
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this for loop it will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
    $('#p' + i + '-show').click(function() {
      $('#p' + i).show();
    });
    $('#p' + i + '-hide').click(function() {
      $('#p' + i).hide();
    });
  }
  /* $('#p1-show').click(function () { $('#p1').show(); });
   $('#p1-hide').click(function () { $('#p1').hide(); });

   $('#p2-show').click(function () { $('#p2').show(); });
   $('#p2-hide').click(function () { $('#p2').hide(); });

   $('#p3-show').click(function () { $('#p3').show(); });
   $('#p3-hide').click(function () { $('#p3').hide(); });

   $('#p4-show').click(function () { $('#p4').show(); });
   $('#p4-hide').click(function () { $('#p4').hide(); });

   //there will be ids' for 300+*/

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```